# copy files with md5-based target name using find and xargs

Tags: find, xargs

I have a directory tree with many *.dat* files, where many of them contain special characters. They are used by another process which is only able to process files containing ascii characters.

My idea was to `find` all the files, build a new file name based on the `md5` hash of their file path, and copy them to a new directory (they aren't very large, and I may not alter the originals).

This is what I've tried

```
find dat -type f -name "*.dat" -print0|xargs -0 -I file cp 'file' "datnew/$(echo file|md5).dat"
```

Unfortuntately it only builds a single hash, and copy all files to that output file name:

```
$ touch dat/foo.dat
$ touch dat/bar.dat
$ find dat -type f -name "*.dat" -print0|xargs -0 -I file cp 'file' "datnew/$(echo file|md5).dat"
$ ls datnew
bbe02f946d5455d74616fc9777557c22.dat
```

Can you please tell me what my mistakte is? Am I using `xargs`in a wrong way?

Comment: what is the output of `echo file | md5`? It should be `bbe02f946d5455d74616fc9777557c22` as `file` will not be interpreted in `$( echo file | md5 )`

Comment: @Fiximan yes, please see the last line of my result. That is exactly how the results looks. Is there any way to get the `file` there to be replaced as well?

Comment: You will need to use `-n1` to the `xargs` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `file` in `$( echo $file | md5 )` will not be interpreted, you need a workaround.

One possibility is to simply pipe it into a `while` loop and read each output - in that case better skip `xargs` as a whole

```
find ... | while read file ; do cp "$file" "datnew/$( echo "$file" | md5 )" ; done
```

For using it with `-print0` replace the null character with a newline using `tr`

```
find ... -print0 | tr '\000\' '\n' | while read ; do ... ; done
```

Comment: this does not seem to work with `-print0` of find, does it? I need this option because of some of the special characters

Comment: replace the null character by a newline with with `tr` : `find -print0 | tr '\000' '\n' | while read ...`